# Remove the field in from laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laraadmin

Two questions, how can I hide or remove the field in from the user profile form?

Second, I have in the form of a label for example Picture:, where can I paddle a symbol :?

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7lUO.png)

Comment: All you can do is to edit the blade that view using.

Answer (score -1):

```
@if($is_user_let_div_show == "yes")

    <div>

    </div>

@endif
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.